# Composer.json say invalid string for php patches as asterisk(*)

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.8

I want to require php like this but it is giving me an error

```
Skipped branch master, Could not parse version constraint ^7.2.*: Invalid version string "^7.2.*"
```

My composer.json file looks like this

```
"require":{
        "php": "^7.2.*",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*"
    },
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that you can use `^7.2` for anything greater than 7.2.0 and you can use `7.2.*`  for anything that starts with 7.2, but you can't use both together. The first will match the second.

Comment: @aynber That is correct, see also https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md

Comment: Just use `"php": ">=7.2.0"`

Comment: Using `>=7.2.0` is not the same as it will also allow PHP 8.

Comment: yes @xabbuh you are right. but that is not the issue. thanks for your feedback